# Securing REST APIs with NGINX

Tags: nginx, authentication

Hi I have an API behind NGINX. The API is configured to require authentication for all actions. I want to have an NGINX proxy in front of it to pass authentication parameters for some of the actions so they can be accessible without authentication.

Authentication works fine on the main location, however when I try to specify specific path in NGXINX location, it still prompts me for credentials.

Important thing here is that the only action I want to allow is STATUS. Everything else shouldn't be picked up by the second location.

Is there a way to do this without PCRE or regex matching?

```
    location / {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
            proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
            proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
             add_header 'Location1' '1';

         location /1/2/3?action=STATUS {
                add_header 'Location2' '2';
                proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic BLAHBLAHBLAH";
                proxy_pass http://backend;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location matching is done against a normalized URI that doesn't contain query string.

So it's necessary to use an if block in this case :

```
location /1/2/3 {

    if ($arg_action != "STATUS") {
        return 403;
    }

    add_header 'Location2' '2';
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic BLAHBLAHBLAH";
    proxy_pass http://backend;

}
```